# Project Euler #11 - Largest product in a grid

Tags: programming-challenge, functional-programming, clojure

## Problem statement

I've tried to solve the following Euler problem in a very straight-forward way, ideally avoiding recursion if possible and writing it in a functional style.

> What is the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same direction (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) in the 20×20 grid?

The full problem statement can be found [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11).

## Implementation

### Data

*problem11.txt*

> 08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
>   49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
>   81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
>   52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
>   22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
>   24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
>   32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
>   67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
>   24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
>   21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
>   78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
>   16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
>   86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
>   19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
>   04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
>   88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
>   04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
>   20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
>   20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
>   01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48

### Code

My program structure is based on calculating the indices of 4-tuples that can be found diagonally, anti-diagonally, horizontally and vertically. I obtain this by reading the input grid into a single vector, then doing some magic to get respectively the diagonal, anti-diagonal, horizontal and vertical lines, and then I partition each line into segments of size 4 with an offset of 1.

*problems/problem11.clj*

```
(ns project-euler.problems.problem11
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [clojure.string :as str]
            [clojure.math.numeric-tower :as math]))

(defn- read-grid []
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader (io/resource "problem11.txt"))]
    (->> (line-seq rdr)
         (str/join " ")
         (#(str/split % #" "))
         (map (comp read-string #(str "10r" %)))
         vec)))

(defrecord coordinate [x y])

(defn- to-coordinate [size n]
  (coordinate. (- n (* size (int (math/floor (/ n size)))))
               (int (math/floor (/ n size)))))

(defn- mirror-horizontal [size coord]
  (coordinate. (- (dec size) (:x coord))
               (:y coord)))

(defn- to-index [size coord]
  (+ (* size (:y coord)) (:x coord)))

(defn- incrementing-by? [n s]
  (apply = n (map - (rest s) s)))

(defn- diagonal-indices-in-grid [size total n]
  (->> (range 0 total)
       (group-by #(mod % (inc size)))
       vals
       (mapcat (partial partition n 1))
       (filter #(incrementing-by? 1 (map (comp :x (partial to-coordinate size)) %)))))

(defn- anti-diagonal-indices-in-grid [size total n]
  (->> (range 0 total)
       (group-by #(mod % (inc size)))
       vals
       (map (partial map #(to-index size (mirror-horizontal size (to-coordinate size %)))))
       (mapcat (partial partition n 1))
       (filter #(incrementing-by? -1 (map (comp :x (partial to-coordinate size)) %)))))

(defn- horizontal-indices-in-grid [size total n]
  (->> (range 0 total)
       (group-by #(:y (to-coordinate size %)))
       vals
       (mapcat (partial partition n 1))))

(defn- vertical-indices-in-grid [size total n]
  (->> (range 0 total)
       (group-by #(:x (to-coordinate size %)))
       vals
       (mapcat (partial partition n 1))))

(defn largest-product-in-grid [n]
  {:pre [(pos? n)]}
  (let [grid (read-grid)
        total (count grid)
        size (int (math/sqrt total))]
    (->> (concat (diagonal-indices-in-grid size total n)
                 (anti-diagonal-indices-in-grid size total n)
                 (horizontal-indices-in-grid size total n)
                 (vertical-indices-in-grid size total n))
         (map (partial map (partial nth grid)))
         (map (partial reduce *))
         (apply max))))

(println (largest-product-in-grid 4))
```

I must admit that the code got a little bit more complicated than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 1):

> I must admit that the code got a little bit more complicated than I thought it would be.

I agree.  Since the problem deals with a grid, to me it's a pretty good fit for a `i . j` matrix type of solution.  This is a great traditional imperative type of problem.  It can be made more functional I suppose, but IMO it's important to tailor the solution to the problem, not the language, and clojure actually is a good fit for it either way.

If we think of the first position where we begin the sum as starting from the top and moving rightwards and downwards (never leftwards and upwards), then for each case (horizontal, vertical, diag left, diag right) we have a clear picture of where the first position can be, and where it can't be.  So from the beginning, for each of the four finite cases, we know, given the grid width, height, and length of the adjacent numbers, which rows are valid/invalid, and which columns are valid/invalid.

- For the vertical case, the starting position can't be on any of the last three rows -- it can be in any column, but must be on row 0-16 (not 17-19).  From the start, we fix the column and add the next 3 rows.
- For horizontal, it can't be on any of the last three columns -- it can be in any row, but must be on column 0-16 (not 17-19).  From the start, we fix the row and add the next 3 columns.
- For the "backslash" diagonal, it can't be on either the last three columns, or the last three rows.  From the start, we increase the row and column, 3 times.
- For the "slash" diagonal, it can't be on either the first three columns, or the last three rows. From the start, we increase the row and decrease the column, 3 times.

For each position, and for each of the 4 cases, we test whether the current position is a valid position, and if it is, add up the elements at the four positions.

The below answer is generalized, so that it can be used on any size grid, with any length.  I hope it's okay to post it here to give an idea.

```
(def width 20)
(def height 20)
(def len 4)

(defn row-col-to-index
  [row col]
  (+ (* row width) col))

(defn value-at [v row col]
  (get v (row-col-to-index row col)))

(defn answer []
  (let [rowmax (- height len)
        colmin (dec len)
        colmax (- width len)
        loopvec (range len)]
    (apply max
      (flatten
        (for [row (range height)
              col (range width)]
          [(if (> row rowmax) 0
            (reduce * (for [i loopvec]
                        (value-at grid (+ row i) col))))
          (if (> col colmax) 0
            (reduce * (for [i loopvec]
                        (value-at grid row (+ col i)))))
          (if (or (> row rowmax) (> col colmax)) 0
            (reduce * (for [i loopvec]
                        (value-at grid (+ row i) (+ col i)))))
          (if (or (> row rowmax) (< col colmin)) 0
            (reduce * (for [i loopvec]
                        (value-at grid (+ row i) (- col i)))))])))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I was are concerned about speed, I'd prefer to tackle this using the sequence library upon a vector of rows.

If we take the first row (removing redundant leading zeros):

```
(def row [8 2 22 97 38 15 0 40 0 75 4 5 7 78 52 12 50 77 91 8])
```

... then the number we want is ...

```
(->> row
     (partition 4 1)
     (map #(apply * %))
     (apply max))
;4204200
```

If we have the whole array as a vector of vectors, we can transpose it with

```
(defn transpose [vss]
  (apply mapv vector vss))
```

For example

```
(transpose [[1 2] [3 4]])
;[[1 3] [2 4]]
```

That deals with rows and columns. You can play similar tricks to get the diagonals, with liberal use of `rest` and `reverse`.